# Python script to control GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, python, user-interface

I am writing my own GUI with .NET (C#) and I want to use a python script to click buttons for me automatically and read from text boxes etc. I've tried the Google searches but nothing really helpful. Is there a library that I need to download for .NET or is there a module in python that will do what i"m looking for. I'm sure it can be done, I just don't know where yo start

Comment: If you're writing the GUI yourself, why would you want this, rather than running it against the underlying layer directly?

Comment: I would recommend using Powershell.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx

Comment: If you write your OWN GUI, why don't you add your OWN c# code click buttons within your OWN code..!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for a test automation tool, to script GUI events.  I looked into using Ranorex for that a while back, and it looked very capable, but it was too expensive and overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

I have used AutoIt in the past for GUI testing where I needed to actually test the GUI controls.

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/